# How to Set Value in React Material UI Fields

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, formik

I have a `message` field that I need to type on. before that I have variable dropdown that I need to APPEND to the `message` field everytime I select on it. My problem is that its overriding it. I'm using formik and Material-UI in React.

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-material-ui-and-yup-forked-mk431?file=/src/form/Form.js)

```
            <Autocomplete
              value={values.variable}
              options={variables}
              getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option === value}
              getOptionLabel={(data) => data}
              onChange={(e, value) => {
                setFieldValue("variable", value);
                setFieldValue("message", value);
              }}
              fullWidth
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  name="variable"
                  size="small"
                  variant="outlined"
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  helperText={touched.variable ? errors.variable : ""}
                  error={touched.variable && Boolean(errors.variable)}
                />
              )}
            />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do overwrite the value every time you select something :).
If you want to append you need the old value of message as well.

```
<Autocomplete
                  value={values.variable}
                  options={variables}
                  getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option === value}
                  getOptionLabel={(data) => data}
                  onChange={(e, value) => {
                    setFieldValue("variable", value);
                    // append the value 
                    setFieldValue("message", `${values.message} ${value}`);
                  }}
                  fullWidth
                  renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...params}
                      name="variable"
                      size="small"
                      variant="outlined"
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                      helperText={touched.variable ? errors.variable : ""}
                      error={touched.variable && Boolean(errors.variable)}
                    />
                  )}
                />
```

Comment: How do i make the `{{ variables }}` only not editable in the `message` TextField?

Comment: That's not an easy task. You could introduce a data structure that represents your message content. But I guess there will be lots of edge cases. You could check out frameworks like https://docs.slatejs.org/ that are made for rich text stuff.